# Dark theme for Thunderbird on macOS?

Tags: color, themes, macos

Does there exist a theme plug-in or add-on that can make the Thunderbird on macOS looks mostly dark or black?

Comment: Searching for "Thunderbird Themes" in Google provides this as the first link. Please research before asking a question.

Answer (score 2):

It's part of the default theme package in current beta versions (running b64).[image: screenshot of theme settings in Thunderbird]

In Mojave, it switches to the dark theme automatically if you change the OS to dark. However, whereas the dark theme in Firefox is pretty much complete, the theme in Thunderbird is haphazardly applied. I'm not running dark mode Mojave specifically because Thunderbird theme is off. See bugzilla entry here: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1486205

Answer (score 0):

Search their themes on their website.
https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/thunderbird/themes/